# Merge two arrays without replacing values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im a bit lost or mind is not working as it should. I read other questions around but can get mine to work.

I got this array:

```
Array
(
    [89] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

And i got this :

```
Array
(
    [84] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [83] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [87] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [88] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [89] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [90] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

I should get all results but on key 89 i should get the value from first array.

```
Array
(
    [84] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [83] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [87] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [88] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [89] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 2
        )

    [90] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

Array merge wont work :( .
Also after i get the result if the first array its :

```
Array
(
    [89] => Array
        (
           [1] => 2
        )

)
```

The resulting array should update to one record.

Im sure its a 1 min code for you gurus but arrays always been a pain for me.

Thanks

UPDATE : if i use array_merge_recursive it wont keep my keys :

```
print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2));
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: You'll need to post the PHP code with which you're doing the merge.

Comment: array mere recursive won't keep the keys because they are numeric...try appending a string prefix to them and it shoul work ok..

Here is what the man says: `If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the values for these keys are merged together into an array, and this is done recursively, so that if one of the values is an array itself, the function will merge it with a corresponding entry in another array too. If, however, the arrays have the same numeric key, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended. `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_merge_recursive` should do the job; look at the documentation for more pointers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

**EDIT**
The function behaved differently than I initially thought, here´s a different version of the function to solve your problem:

```
function array_merge_recursive_distinct(array &$array1, array &$array2) {
  $merged = $array1;

  foreach($array2 as $key => &$value) {
    if(is_array($value) && isset($merged[$key]) && is_array($merged[$key])) {
      $merged[$key] = array_merge_recursive_distinct($merged[$key], $value);
    } else {
      $merged[$key] = $value;
    }
  }

  return $merged;
}
```

Thanks to the community of php.net http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195

Comment: Great Kolky!! thats working when adding values but how can i make it work on the second case? I mean i run it once and it add values to key 89 , but now i give a new array with just one value on key 89. the new resulting array should remove value that not exist any more...

Comment: That's not an array merge anymore!

Comment: So what i really need its a function to compare two arrays and update the second one with the values of first one? Shall i open another question for this?

Comment: I got it working by function array_merge_recursive_distinct( $array1,  $array2)
{
  $merged = $array1;

  foreach($array2 as $key => $value)
  {
   
 if(array_key_exists($key,$array1)){
  
  unset($merged[$key]);
  $merged[$key]=$value;
 }   
  }

  return $merged;
}

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly, [adding arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) should suffice:

```
$result_array = $array1 + $array2;
```

In contrast to [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), it won't overwrite values in first array and won't renumber numerical keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray=array();

foreach(array_merge($array1,$array2) as $k=>$arr){
    $newarray[$k]=array_merge($array1[$k],$array2[$k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($firstArr as $key=>$val){
    if(in_array($key,$secondArray)){
        $secondArray[$key] = $firstArr[$key];
    }
}
```

Try this may help you.